# SQL Server replication: how to find out what suscriptors are attached to a distributor

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have access to a SQL Server with replication which I haven't set up.

I have found one publisher and one distributor in the SSMS, but I can't find information about the suscriptor.

I know the suscriptor is in other server, but I expected to find some information in the publisher/distributor server.

How can I find out some information regarding the suscriptors attached to a certain distributor?

Comment: Have you tried "Replication|Launch Replication Monitor" on any of the sql instances?

Comment: I have just tried it and it displays the information. Thanks a lot.